# How to convert float to fraction in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to convert a float value of 0.125 into fraction as 1/8, so that I can display it on a UILabel.

I receive the float value from the server and need to load that in UITableView in a fraction format.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895154/decimal…

Comment: Is it always something/8? Seems more of a maths problem rather a Swift one.

Comment: Look here :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968636/converting-a-float-into-a-string-fraction-representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968636/converting-a-float-into-a-string-fraction-representation)

Comment: Checkout https://swiftpackageregistry.com/davidwkeith/FractionFormatter